# Lightroom adjustment brush settings or shortcuts

Tags: lightroom, keyboard-shortcuts, brushes

Working in Lightroom and suddenly my 'adjustment brush' tool is auto masking the entire photo I am editing. I must have hit a key on the keyboard. The 'auto mask' box is unchecked (I tried checking the box as well and it does the same thing), 'range mask' is off (I do not think I use this option), and I have restarted the program with no change.

Upon further inspection I tried editing a different photo and the brush did not act the same, I went forward two photos and the brush again acted normal. I removed the photo with the brush issue and re-imported back in. The brush works normally again. What happened?

Is there a keyboard shortcut that I have accidentally turned on this auto-masking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The auto of the brush tool does not seem to be in relation with the problem described as it is a setting to activate automatic mask border in course of brushing.

As you  indicate, most likely, is that you have activated a shortcut, and we will probably never know what it is.

Well, with everything back to normal, it's not too bad.

However, if it happens again, you should try to see if it's a brush mask, or as I think a gradient mask.

Answer (score 0):

This week it has happened twice this week. I tried re-starting Lightroom and the computer. Previously this issue was only happening in one image. Now its happening in multiple. I had an idea it was a glitch in one of my brushes, I deleted the suspecting brush and tried another. I cannot figure out this problem.

I only use brushes, I do not use gradients. Auto mask is turned off.

Comment: Just to check a fool idea, what is the size of your brush ?

Comment: As it seems reprodyctible, can you describe exactly when this happens ?
Start with a non edited file.